# Uniformly Pick Row and Uniformly Pick Column == Uniformly Pick Matrix Entry??

Tags: probability, matrices

Let $A$ be $M \times N$ matrix. I need to sample a entry uniformly from the matrix. If I sample a row (pick a number among integers $1,\dots,M$) and sample a column, both uniformly, is it equivalent to picking a entry uniformly across the matrix?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. The probability of picking the $i$-th row and $j$-th column is then

$$P(row=i, col=j) = P(row=i| col=j)\cdot P(col = j) =\\= P(row=i)\cdot P(row=j) = \frac{1}{M}\cdot \frac1N = \frac1{MN}$$

which is the probability of picking one of $MN$ objects uniformly by random.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if the row and column are selected independently. If $(I,J)$ is the random cell you are trying to select, then using this scheme 
$$P\left((I,J)=(i,j)\right)=P(I=i,J=j)\stackrel{(1)}=P(I=i)P(J=j)=\frac1M\frac1N=\frac1{MN}\;,$$
so every cell has the same chance of being selected. Note independence of $I$ and $J$ is used in (1).